# Come usare "improbabile" per una cosa che non piace affatto?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Mi hanno detto che si può usare l'aggettivo "improbabile" per esprimere l'idea che una cosa non ci piace affatto.

Il senso sarebbe che una cosa ci sembra di un gusto tanto cattivo che ci pare improbabile di poter trovare qualcosa di simile a quella.

Ma come si può usare alla pratica in un contesto determinato? Potreste farmi qualche esempio di uso di questo aggettivo con questo significato?

Comment: Mi sembra un uso un po' improbabile...

Comment: Forse è un uso più o meno spiritoso di qualcuno in particolare, ma non mi sembra molto generalizzato (pur essendo comprensibile). Un mio amico, per esempio, usa in un senso simile “maleducato” (detto appunto di qualcosa sgradevole); per quanto comprensibile e creativo, non lo considererei un uso standard.

Comment: @DaG: Forse un esempio di questo uso è quello che se ne fa qui: https://books.google.es/books?id=umGuAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&ots=uk6GE2kYJY&focus=viewport&dq=improbabile+cattivo+gusto#v=onepage&q=improbabile%20cattivo%20gusto&f=false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ma come si può usare alla pratica in un contesto determinato? Potreste farmi qualche esempio di uso di questo aggettivo con questo significato?

Un'auto di colore improbabile; un caffè di sapore improbabile. Ci si può trovare un compagno improbabile, e si possono avere gusti improbabili nel vestire (per es., le *mise* di [Giannino](http://www.fashionblog.it/post/54289/i-look-piu-eccentrici-di-oscar-giannino-candidato-alle-elezioni-2013) sono state più volte definite *giacche improbabili*).

Nessuno di questi è un complimento :-). Ricordo una signora inglese che usava nello stesso senso il giro di parole *raro a trovarsi* (una volta me lo chiarì molto esplicitamente aggiungendo, "*...ci vuole una bella sfortuna!*").

Answer (score 2):

Su [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/improbabile/), oltre al significato relativo ad una evento che difficilmente si avvererà, viene riportato:

> Poco verosimile, che difficilmente può corrispondere alla realtà, e
>   perciò poco credibile: una situazione, una trama i. (in un racconto,
>   in un film); un personaggio improbabile.

***Quel film ha una trama improbabile*** significa che la pellicola è inverosimile e perciò, per estensione di scarsa qualità.

Lo stesso se l'aggettivo viene applicato ad una persona che dovrebbe avere un incarico ma è palesemente incapace di eseguirlo correttamente.

Ad esempio, ***l'ispettore Clouseau è un investigatore improbabile*** in quanto, sebbene adorabile, è imbranato, inetto e pasticcione.

Un altro esempio: ***il proprietario dell'azienda si presentava sempre con vestiti tanto opulenti quanto improbabili***, cioè con vestiti che avevano lo scopo di apparire eleganti ma alla fine erano di pessimo gusto.

Comment: Non sono sicura che l'esempio dell'ispettore Clouseau sia la stessa cosa perché si tratta di un personaggio che ci può piacere nonstante possiamo trovarlo inetto nel suo lavoro, ma capisco che l'uso d'"improbabile" in questa ultima frase va in una linea più o meno simile.

Comment: Il discorso è che l'aggettivo improbabile si riferisce al fatto che il personaggio non è all'altezza del ruolo che ricopre, e non al fatto che sia amabile o meno